# Reducing if-statements in a Pokemon element type system

Tags: c++, if-statement

Im in the process of trying to create a simple pokemon battle simulator in C++. The problem Ive ran into now is how to implement the Element system (water beats fire, fire beats grass, grass beats water, and including all the other element types).

I dont know how I would create such a system without having to use a ton of If statements. Is there a better way to do this?

I have a good amount of general programming knowledge, and I know the basics of C++, like classes, loops, and various other basic things.

I would provide code, but there is nothing to provide as I have no idea how to make such a system. I guess i'm asking for what kind of technique, data structure, etc I could use to accomplish this

Comment: We're not here to do the work for you. We help with problems you run into while doing your OWN work. So, please post what you have tried so far and then we surely can help you!

Comment: I would use a *lookup table* or *decision matrix*.

Comment: A decision matrix looks like it would work. Thanks for the input

Comment: You need to show some code to narrow down what you are asking; we have no idea whether you know C++ or if you're asking this in complete abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a *lookup table* or *decision matrix*.

Imagine this table, for Rock-Paper-Scissors

```
   R  P  S
R  -  L  W
P  W  -  L
S  L  W  -
```

And where it is interpreted as so, reading ROW then COL

```
ROW(R) at COL(R) -> R *ties* R
ROW(S) at COL(P) -> S *wins* P
```

(The two diagonal halves of the matrix are inverted mirrors in this case.)