# Trying to make a rock paper scissor game, to only run one game/ enum coding confusion

Tags: java, random

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Branches {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        enum Gesture {
            rock,
            paper,
            scissors
        }

        Scanner tKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter “S” for scissors, “R” for rock, or “P” for paper.");
        int tChoice = tKeyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println(tChoice);
        Random tRNG = new Random();
        int tX = tRNG.nextInt(3);
        if (tX > )
            System.out.println("You lose.");
        else if (tX < tChoice)
            System.out.println("You win.");
        else 
            System.out.println("It is a tie.");     

    }

}
```

This is my code so far, I know it's greatly lacking but I've different things and I cant figure it out.
I need to run one game of rock paper scissors. It's supposed to start out asking the user to enter a choice, rock paper or scissors.
Then the computer is supposed to randomly aside the opposing team a number: 0,1 or 2
After that an enum is supposed to be made to assign those numerical values to actual variables from the enum - Rock, paper & scissors.
After that the users choice is supposed to compared with the opposing teams random choice using if/else statements so that the winner can be picked based upon a normal rock paper & scissors game.

Comment: Not an (or a complete) answer, but [consider using a matrix to represent RPS win/lost logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585417/reducing-if-statements-in-a-pokemon-element-type-system/23585577#23585577). Whatever is done, hide the logic in a function then `int result = fight(firstPlayerChoice, secondPlayerChoice); if (result == ..) ..` can be trivially used, where (eg.) said "fight" function returns -1 [first player wins], 0 [tie] or 1 [second player wins].

Comment: You are asking the user to enter a character, but you're reading integer `tKeyboard.nextInt()` ?

Comment: `if (tX > )` ??? also, you can't declare an enum inside a method. Please post a code that can be compiled!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a character but requesting an integer.
However, this should help you out. Even though the way the game is played will be sort of odd, this works.

```
package gui;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    enum Gesture 
    {
        rock(1),
        paper(2),
        scissors(3);

        private int type;
        Gesture(int type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public int getType(){ return type; }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter “S” for scissors, “R” for rock, or “P” for paper.");
        final String choice = keyboard.next();

        if (choice.equals("S")) {
             generateDraw(Gesture.scissors);
        } 
        else if (choice.equals("R")) {
            generateDraw(Gesture.rock);
        } 
        else if (choice.equals("P")) {
            generateDraw(Gesture.paper);
        }

        keyboard.close();
    }

    public static void generateDraw(Gesture gesture) {
        final Random random = new Random();
        final int computerDraw = random.nextInt(3);
        System.out.println(computerDraw);

        if (computerDraw > gesture.getType()) {
            System.out.println("You lose.");
        }
        else if (computerDraw < gesture.getType()) {
             System.out.println("You win.");
        }  
        else {
                System.out.println("It is a tie.");


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A simple `<`/`>` *can't* be used for RPS due to the "wrap-around" nature, assigning R=1, P=2, S=3, S loses to R (where S > R) but S aso wins to P (also where S > P). It is also cleaner to entirely separate the input (including the computer choice) from the battle/win-lose resolution.